# Deleted resources in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

Someone deleted the deployment and i tried to find out from the event logs but i found below response:
No resources found in prometheus namespace.

Is there plugin or something to let me know who deleted this resource?

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes auditing provides a security-relevant, chronological set of records documenting the sequence of actions in a cluster. The cluster audits the activities generated by users, by applications that use the Kubernetes API, and by the control plane itself.

As per the [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/):

> Auditing allows cluster administrators to answer the following
> questions:
>
> what happened?
>
> when did it happen?
>
> who initiated it?
>
> on what did it happen?
>
> where was it observed?
>
> from where was it initiated?
>
> to where was it going?